# What's the easiest way to develop an integration code with Android's (Google play) in-app billing from a developer's POV?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I read that you need to need to publish the app with the original key, define products, etc.

Does this mean I can't do change-debug code cycles and I'll need to republish the code on every little change I want to debug?

Is there an easier way of developing in-app purchase integration?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to publish the app in the early stages of the in-app billing process.

You can check try to use what is suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html).

There you can see there are 2 types of testing. You are interested in [testing with static responses](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static).

Comment: Have you tried the `android.test.purchased` yourself? There are several issues with it. For example, it doesn't support subscriptions. Another issue is that after using it, trying to query inventory will result in a failure: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed.

Comment: I used it about a year ago for a project and I don't have the source files anymore... I know I used the static responses and they were working for me (I didn't have any subscriptions so I didn't know about it not supporting them but the inventory was working well at the time).